# Send an email to current user in SQL Server Agent job when job fails

Tags: sql-server, email, sql-server-agent

I have a `SQL Job` where I want to send an email alert if job fails. I know that for this functionalty I have to  `Configure Database Mail` and than `Adjust the properties within the SQL Server Agent`. This article gives pretty good detail http://www.sherweb.com/blog/how-to-set-up-database-mail-for-sql-server-job-failures/.

What I want is, instead of setting up an email address to particular user like `person1@test.com`, I want to send an email to current user. This way who ever logged in to database and runs the job receives the email on job failure.

As I see, there are two benefits of this approach, 
i. One particular user won't get flooded with emails. ii. Who ever is running the job can know that job has failed.

For example,
If I set `person1@test.com` and person2 logs in than on job failure person1 will receive an email. I don't want that. Is there any way that I can do this in `SQL Server Agent Job` settings. If no than how can I achieve this?

Like `SELECT SYSTEM_USER` or `SELECT SUSER_NAME()` gives me current user and use that as outgoing email address.

Comment: does this mean ,jobs are not automated as per schedule and only user can run job manually?

Comment: Further can you clarify what do you mean by user logged

Comment: @TheGameiswar Job is automated and runs on every half an hour. For example, if I add my name as email recipient in job and tomorrow  5 different people sets the request than I will receive an email. I want other 5 people to receive the email. Make sense?

Comment: What do you mean by set the requests?

Comment: @TheGameiswar User can set `Daily` or `Weekly` option to fire certaion query from UI. I store the start date, start time and desired time to execute in table. I've a `stored procedure` which checks the condition and picks the records from that `table` if it matches the condition. `SQL job` will execute this `stored procedure` on every half an hour. If job fails than send email to person.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused, if one user will start the job manually then you use a `STORE PROCEDURE` and there you can get the `connected user` information.

But `pgAgent` will run the process automatic and run using the `USER` you setup on the job.